# Numerical comparison in Python

Tags: python

I'm working with very large numbers such as: 632382 to the power of 518061.

When I try calculating it directly using Python (`632382**518061`), it takes a really long time.

However, when I compare 2 very large numbers:

```
>>> 632382**518061 > 519432**525806
True
```

Python does it very quickly.

I assumed that in order to compare both numbers, Python would calculate them beforehand. But since the comparison is much faster than its actual calculation, Python is doing something different.

How is Python able to perform the comparison much faster (apparently without calculating the exact values)?

Comment: How quick is "very quickly"?

Comment: "I assumed that in order to compare both numbers, Python would calculate them beforehand. But since the comparison is much faster than its actual calculation, Python is doing something different." I don't believe you, you are going to have to show us your profiling attempts, I suspect they are invalid.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What takes so long is printing the values.

If I enter

```
>>> x = 632382**518061
```

in an interactive Python session, it takes about a second.

If I then enter

```
>>> x
```

it takes at least half a minute (I aborted it before it generated any output).<sup>1</sup>

Evaluating and printing the result of the expression `632382**518061 > 519432**525806` does not require printing the two large numbers, therefore it takes less time.

It still takes longer than evaluating the two numbers (without printing), as expected:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> timeit('632382**518061', number=1)
1.312588474999984
>>> timeit('519432**525806', number=1)
1.281405287000041
>>> timeit('632382**518061 > 519432**525806', number=1)
2.685868804999984
```

---

<sup>1</sup>After all, the decimal representation of `x` has 3005262 digits, which we can calculate much more quickly than with `len(str(x))` [by using logarithms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2178989/finding-digits-of-large-exponent):

```
>>> from math import log10, ceil
>>> ceil(518061 * log10(632382))
3005262
```

Comment: I wonder whether it's the printing or the conversion to string...

Comment: It's at least the conversion to string, `len(str(x))` takes very long. Not sure if printing adds significantly. Feel free to measure the durations for `s = str(x)` and `print(x)` ;-)

Comment: Probably depends on where I print it. I'd guess  IDLE/cmd/powershell/whatever windows have different speeds. I always remove any printing before I benchmark something, feels wrong to measure it :-)